# A question concerning the proof of the "Carathéodory criterion"

Tags: measure-theory

After doing some research on the internet it appeared to me that in the english speaking math world the terminology (def., name of theorems,...) is a bit different than in the german one. So I'll first give the definitions as I know them, then what I know as the "Carathéodory criterion", its proof and last my question concerning the proof.

A map $\mu:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to [0,\infty] $ is called an outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $\mu(\{ \})=0$ and $\mu(A)\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i) $ for all $A\subset A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... $.

A subset $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called $\mu$-measurable if \begin{equation}\mu(B)=\mu(B\cap A)+\mu(B    \setminus A)\end{equation} for all $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $\mathcal{A}_{\mu} $denote the set of all  $\mu$-measurable sets.

It is known that $\mathcal{A}_{\mu} $  is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Let furthermore $\mathcal{B}$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now what I know as the "Carathéodory criterion":
Let $\mu$ be an outer measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with \begin{equation}
\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)
\end{equation}
for all sets $ A,B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $\inf \{d(a,b): a \in A, b \in B \}=:dist(A,B)>0. $ Then $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{A}_{\mu}.$

Proof. It is enough to show \begin{equation}\mu(A)\geq \mu(A\cap C)+\mu(A\setminus C)
\end{equation}
for all closed sets $C$ and arbitrary sets $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n.$ Because this is obviously true for sets with $\mu(A)=+\infty $ we may wlog assume $\mu(A)<+\infty$. Define the sets $C_n:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: dist(x,C)\leq \frac{1}{n}\}$. Due to \begin{equation}
\mu(A\setminus C_n)+\mu(A\cap C)=\mu(A\setminus C_n \cup A\cap C)\leq\mu(B),\end{equation}
as $dist(A\setminus C_n, A\cap C)>\frac{1}{n}>0$, it is sufficient to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(A\setminus C_n)=\mu(A\setminus C).$
To see this set $R_k:=A\cap (C_k\setminus C_{k+1}).$ Then $A\setminus C=(A\setminus C_k) \cup R_k \cup R_{k+1}\cup ... $ and therefore
\begin{equation}\mu(A\setminus C_n)\leq \mu (A\setminus C)\leq \mu(A\setminus C_n)+\sum_{i=n}^\infty \mu(R_i).
\end{equation}
If $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(R_i)<\infty$ taking the limit and using the last inequality would finish the proof. Observe that $ dist(R_i,R_j)>0$ for $ |i-j|\geq 2$. Therefore, by using the assumption on $\mu$ we get \begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(R_i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(R_{2i})+\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mu(R_{2i+1})=\mu(R_2\cup R_4\cup ...)+\mu(R_1\cup R_3\cup...)\leq 2\mu(A)<\infty,
\end{equation}
which finishes the proof.

My question is now the following: Where is it used in the proof that (C) is closed or why does this proof doesn't work for all sets (C)? Apart from that the proof makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closedness of $C$ is used for

> Then $A \setminus C = (A \setminus C_k) \cup R_k \cup R_{k+1} \cup \dotsc$.

Since each $R_k$ consists only of points having a positive distance from $C$, the union also contains only points with positive distance from $C$. Points in $\overline{C} \setminus C$ have distance $0$ from $C$, and hence aren't covered by the union. Thus the argument only works for sets $A$ with $A \cap (\overline{C}\setminus C) = \varnothing$. Having $C$ closed ensures that.